# continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity

Let $T=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :|z|=1\}$ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=2$.  I need to show that there exists at least one $t_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(t_0)\in T$.  Do I need to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem?  I guess there will be some point $x\in [0,1]$ for which $f(x)=(1,0)\in \text{ i.e } 1\in T$ choose $t_0=x$?

Comment: Hint: consider $|f|$.

Comment: I dont get, sorry?

Comment: $|f|$ is a continuous real-valued function from $[0,1]$ to an interval containing $[0,2]$ - invoke IVT on *it*. (You can't simply say $f(x)=1$ in the complex plane because the image of $f$ could trace out a path *around* the point $1$ in $\Bbb C$; considering drawing examples to help your intuition.)

Comment: You need to find a point $t_0$ such that $|f(t_0)| = 1$.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as complex analysis instead of real analysis ?

Comment: @Belgi good point.  It's got hints of both, so I've added complex and kept real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermediate value theorem is applicable in real calculus but does *not* hold for complex numbers. We no longer have only intervals in the complex plane - we have *paths* - and unlike in one dimension there are many different paths between two complex numbers.

Indeed, in our case a function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ could trace out a path from $0$ to $2$ that goes *around* the point $w=1$, so it is not necessarily the case that there is a $t$ for which $f(t)=1$. Geometrically, we can describe the set $\{|f|=1:f\in\Bbb C\}$ as the unit circle. The point $0$ is inside the circle and the point $2$ is outside, so what we're looking to prove, *intuitively*, is that any path from the inside to the outside of the unit circle must *intersect* the unit circle somewhere.

The trick to doing this is to reduce the situation down to real variables where we *can* invoke IVT. To do this, consider the function $g(t)=|f(t)|$ that maps $[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$. It is a real function such that we have the endpoints $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=2$, the absolute value function is continuous and the composition of continuous maps is continuous, so $g$ is continuous, and finally we want to say there's a $t$ for which $g(t)=1$...

Comment: You can't have Intermediate value theorem in Complex analysis because inequalities like $a+bi < c+di$ does not apply.